# Question about setting up my Steam cache server

Tags: steam

New user here, I'm trying to setup my steam cache server using ubuntu and im just curious if its possible to store my steam cache on an LVM that i have set up on 4 hard drives which are NOT my ubuntu OS drive???

Any help would be very welcome thanks.

Martin

I'm assuming the `/SVR/steamcache/depot` is by default stored on the same drive as the OS is , but I would like to put it on my LVM if possible.

Answer (score 0):

/srv/steamcache/depot is like any linux directory node, you can either use it as a local directory, or as a mount point bound to a physical partition on any of the systems drives or network storage.

Comment: Thanks for that info. So here's where my lmv is located according to the "other locations" tab in "files": /Dev/dm-0 it is my 6.5TB lvm pool and I'd like the srv/steamcache/data directory to be placed in here. I already created the /srv/steamcache/data directory and it is currently located at: /computer/the directory where all the other folders such as etc , boot, cdrom are.

Comment: Sorry I find what you said confusing. By "**/computer/the directory where all the other folders such as etc , boot, cdrom are**", I think you mean the system root directory which is /, so under there you should have created a directory structure of **/srv/steamcache/depot**, then you create a suitably sized lv from your lvm2 pool, format it with a file system, and mount it under **/srv/steamcache/depot**. Finally create an entry in fstab for the lv mount so it is persistent through boots.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So I got everything mounted and good to go, but upon getting near to the end of my steam cache server setup, when I try to download and run the two docker images I get an error similar to this one : driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint and also : Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:80:80: bind: address already in use not sure what I'm doing wrong I have set my IP in etc/network/interfaces and ports I'm trying to use are 80:80 and 53:53 at work now so don't have access to my Linux box but will check it out tonight.

Comment: Also what filesystem should I mount to my /svr/steamcache/depot/ I set it up with ntfs as the pc clients i am going to be serving to are windows machines , but i have no idea if i should have used ext3 ext4 or ntfs for my steamcache location on the steam cache server.\

Comment: Personally I would have used ext4, but I don't think it really matters which file system you use. As for your port 80 issue, it sounds like you are already using that port on your system, you probably have apache running, so either stop apache if you are not intentionally running the web server or change the port that steam cache uses.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for sounding extremely ignorant, but how exactly would i set my steam cache to use a different port (is this possible??) the guide i was following was this one from arstechinica : https://arstechnica.com/gaming/2017/01/building-a-local-steam-caching-server-to-ease-the-bandwidth-blues/2/

I am however not very linux savvy and am really struggling with the port 80 error. i removed all containers after stopping them and tried to re-run this :

docker run   --restart unless-stopped   --name steamcache   -p 192.168.1.141:80:80   -v /cache/steam/data:/data/cache   -v /cache/steam/logs:/data/logs   steamcache/steamcache:latest
docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint steamcache (c1b77767abd9ff0986f6aebb259b849831257e294222277c319169390932f64c): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 192.168.1.141:80: bind: address already in use.
ERRO[0002] error waiting for container: context canceled

<